# json to java hashmap using complex key

Tags: java, json, hashmap, key, deserialization

I am currently working on an app in which I need to serialize a 
`HashMap<Object1, Object2>` into JSON and then deserialize from JSON to the same `HashMap'.

I am able to serialize it using the usual mapper and overriding the `toString()` method for `Object1`.

```
public String toString(){
    String res = Object1.elem1 + ";" + Object1.elem2;
    return res
}
```

I am then able to serialize and get the expected json (where res is the String I defined before easier not to write it all back).*

```
{res : Object2JsonRepresentation}
```

Then I want to deserialize, so I use a custom keyDeserializer :

```
@XmlElement(name="myMap")
@JsonDeserialize(keyUsing = Object1KeyDeserializer.class)
public HashMap <Object1,Object2> myMap  = new HashMap <>();
```

And the `Object1KeyDeserializer`:

```
public class Object1KeyDeserializer extends KeyDeserializer{
    @Override
    public Object1 deserializeKey(String key, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        String[] parts = key.split(";");
        System.out.println(key);
        Elem elem1 = new Elem(parts[1]);
        Elem elem2 = new Elem(parts[2]);
        Object1 obj = new Object1(elem1,elem2);
        return obj;
    }
}
```

Nonetheless, the `keyDeserializer` never seems to be called, can you explain me the reason. I'm quite new to JSON and would be glad if answers could be detailed.

Comment: Putting annotations is usually not enought in itself. You will need to configure some plugin in your build somewhere to pick up the annotations and do the work. Please provide more detail about how you are building your application.

Comment: Well it is a part of a bigger app in developpement and the building job is done using gradle.
For the json, I use ObjectMapper and writeValueAsString. To deserialize I do mapper.readValue(jsonString, type)

Comment: @AdriaanKoster what has a runtime annotation that should be evaluated at runtime by Jackson to do with changing the build? Annotations can be used for more than for generating stuff at build time.

Comment: Thank you for answering, nonetheless I don't really understand where we are getting to.

Comment: In the build it is usually specified which dependencies are present and which plugins and processors are applied to the project life cycle. If the @JsonDeserialize annotation is not being picked up as expected, I would start looking at the build to see if anything is missing.

Comment: Oh, and thanks @Vampire for reformating my post !

Comment: @NathanaëlEON What is exacly the error you are seeing? Or which snippet of code is being run and not doing what you expect?

Comment: Well everything runs out well, no build error or anything, I juste get a null object when doing mapper.readValue instead of a Hashmap

Comment: Could it be the JSON you are trying to deserialize is invalid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using toString() you can create your own serialization format. If you have non primitive key in Map then you can serialize Map as

```
[
    {
        "key": <serialized key>,
        "value: <serialized value>
    },
    ....
]
```

In this case your Serializer and Deserializer will be following:

```
public class CustomSerializer extends StdSerializer<Map<Object1, Object2>> {

    protected CustomSerializer() {
        super(Map.class, true);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(Map<Object1, Object2> map,
                          JsonGenerator jsonGenerator,
                          SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException{

        jsonGenerator.writeStartArray();
        for (Map.Entry<Object1,Object2> element: map.entrySet()) {
            jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();
            jsonGenerator.writeObjectField("key", element.getKey());
            jsonGenerator.writeObjectField("value", element.getValue());
            jsonGenerator.writeEndObject();
        }
        jsonGenerator.writeEndArray();
    }
}
```

and

```
public class CustomDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Map<Object1, Object2>> {
    protected CustomDeserializer() {
        super(Map.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Map<Object1, Object2> deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser,
                                             DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException {
        Map<Object1, Object2> result = new HashMap<>();
        JsonNode node = jsonParser.getCodec().readTree(jsonParser);
        for (JsonNode element : node) {
            result.put(
                    jsonParser.getCodec().treeToValue(element.get("key"), Object1.class),
                    jsonParser.getCodec().treeToValue(element.get("value"), Object2.class)
            );
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

So you can create class with your field and another Map (for checking that maps with different types works as usual):

```
public class MapWrapper {

    @JsonSerialize(using = CustomSerializer.class)
    @JsonDeserialize(using = CustomDeserializer.class)
    private Map<Object1, Object2> map = new HashMap<>();

    private Map<String, String> someMap = new HashMap<>();

    // default constructor, getters, setters
}
```

Serialized value can be following:

```
{
  "map": [
    {
      "key": {
        "elem1": "qqq",
        "elem2": "rrr"
      },
      "value": {
        "fieldFromValue": "xxx"
      }
    },
    {
      "key": {
        "elem1": "qqq_two",
        "elem2": "rrr_two"
      },
      "value": {
        "fieldFromValue": "yyy"
      }
    }
  ],
  "someMap": {
    "key1": "value1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer. Nonetheless, instead of serializing, it sill uses toString(). There must be something with the annotation that doesn't get interpreted however I don't know why.

Comment: My bad, I just forgot to initialize the simpleModule with the serializer, therefore, your solution worked perfectly !

THANK YOU !

Comment: I could resolve my issue using this mechanism. Thanks a lot.